# COUNT only one instance between two columns where 3rd column have specific value in EXCEL formula

Tags: excel, count, multiple-columns

Please can you help me in excel. I cannot figure it out how to count only one instance where two columns have any value and where 3rd column have specific value like "cat".

Example:

```html
A    |B       |C
ID540|S3000   |cat    =1

A    |B       |C
SD-10|        |cat    =1

A    |B       |C
     |436346  |cat    =1
```

So, if the "cat" is selected then excel goes through A, B and C rows.
The sum would be "1".

Any clues ? Big thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do this with a formula or with VBA?  What do you mean, "goes through"? In those 3 examples the result is all "1".  When would it be a different value, like "0"?

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this many ways. `COUNTIFS` or `SUMPRODUCT` are two ways I can think of off the top of my head. I prefer `SUMPRODUCT`.

The following formula will return `1` if the `A` and `B` columns contain any value, and the `C` column specifically contains the text `cat`: (Otherwise, `0` is returned)

```
= SUMPRODUCT(COUNTA(A1),COUNTA(B1),(C1="cat")+0)
```

Type this formula into cell `D1` and drag down as far as necessary.

**EDIT**

Based on discussion, formula should be this:

```
= ((SUMPRODUCT((ISBLANK($A3:$B1002))+0)=0)+0)*((SUMPRODUCT((C3:C1002<>"cat")+0)=0)+0)
```

**EDIT** *(again)*

Based on *further* discussion, formula should be this: (line break added for readability)

```
= ((SUMPRODUCT(ISBLANK($A3:$A1002)+0)=0)+0)*
  ((SUMPRODUCT(ISBLANK($M3:$M1002)+0)=0)+0)*
  ((SUMPRODUCT((C3:C1002<>"cat")+0)=0)+0)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Actually excel now shows #VALUE! in D in some reason. 

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTA($A:$A);COUNTA($B:$B);($C:$C="cat")+0)

Comment: @tuunik No problem. If this answer works for you, you should place a checkmark next to it. If it doesn't work, let me know what is not working.

Comment: The C needs to go through all rows but i dont know why it give me error if i type like this: =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTA($A:$A);COUNTA($B:$B);($C:$C="cat")+0)

Comment: @tuunik Ok... so you want the formula to return 1 if **all** cells in the `A` and `B` column are populated and also if **all** cells in the `C` column contain `cat`?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i am looking for :)
To be exact, then not all but from row 3 to row 1002
(A3:A1002, B3:B1002 and C3:C1002)

Comment: @tuunik Interesting request... I am surprised that you have literally every single cell in the `A` and `B` column populated with something and also that every single cell in the `C` column contains the word `cat`. But hey, I'm not one to judge. I will edit my post momentarily with updated formula.

Comment: yes, cat means some category name and the A and B contains id's

Comment: @tuunik Oh wait, I missed the fact that you only go from row 3 to row 1002. That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @tuunik See above, I edited my post to account for this change.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is working now, but the thing is that the A and B actually was for example, In reality need the A and M row not A and B. How to write that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @tuunik sigh... I wish you would have told me it was `A` and `M` row because that changes the formula slightly. This is why you should detail your question in your original post rather than having a long discussion after an answer is already provided to tweak the answer. Anyway, if this formula works for you, you should place a checkmark next to it.

Comment: Yes, i am sorry for the hassle caused.

Comment: @tuunik See my post, I edited the answer as necessary.

Comment: Intrestingly the formula gives value of 0.

Screenshot: 
http://oi64.tinypic.com/5fktqw.jpg

Comment: @tuunik Please post any screen shots in your actual post. Also, the formula *will* return a value of 0 *if* column `A` is missing values, column `M` is missing values, or if column `C` doesn't have the word `cat` in *all* of the rows from 3 to 1002. There's nothing interesting about the formula returning 0. The formula can only return a value of 0 or 1.

Comment: What i mean is that as you can see the answer should not be 0, but the answer should be 3, because there is 3 rows with data, and A and M in each row has a value.

Comment: @tuunik Sorry, I cannot help you anymore. Per my previous comment, I asked the following question verbatim: *Ok... so you want the formula to return 1 if all cells in the A and B column are populated and also if all cells in the C column contain cat?* and you responded *Yes that is exactly what I am looking for*. Your requirements have changed several times and have now changed again. I am not wasting anymore time with this question. In the future, please **take the time to word your question very accurately** from the beginning to avoid the this constant back and forth.

Comment: The requirements haven't changed only i did not explain enough at the start. I am sorry for that, i did not mean to complicate things, i tried to explain what i need and tried my best to understand you.

Comment: @tuunik I realize you are not *intentionally* making requirement changes. You always knew what you wanted from the start. But for the people trying to help you on this site, we don't know what you are trying to accomplish unless you tell us **all** of the details. There is nothing wrong with giving sample data to simplify the problem (in fact, it is often encouraged), but in this case it ended up being so simplified to the point where the formula had to be modified again. Compounding this, you said that something was *exactly* what you wanted, when in fact it ended up not being that.